# sameach vs. samach

Tags: blessing, hebrew, wedding, shemoneh-esrei, nusach-ari

*Nusach S'farad*, in the *amida* ("*sh'mone esre*") of holidays and *Shabas*, has "וְשַׂמַּח נַפְשֵׁינוּ בִּישׁוּעָתֶךָ" ("v'samach..."), but in *sheva b'rachos* it has "שַׂמֵּחַ תְּשַׂמַּח" ("sameach...").

*Nusach Haari* does the opposite: in the *amida* it has "וְשַׂמֵּחַ נַפְשֵׁינוּ בִּישׁוּעָתֶךָ" ("v'sameach..."), but in *sheva b'rachos* it has "שַׂמַּח תְּשַׂמַּח" ("samach...").

Why?

Comment: This is really seeking two separate answers — one, why _nusach S'farad_ does what it does, and, two, why _nusach Haari_ does what it does. The answers may well relate to one another, but if someone can answer just one of those two, he should, please!

Comment: those are two different words: שַׂמַּח is past tense and שַׂמֵּחַ is present tense so the translation is differs. However I don't know the reason for that.

Comment: @jutky, no, they are both, I'm pretty sure, imperatives (masculine singular) in _piel_. The past you may be thinking of is שָׂמַח (masculine singular third person in _kal_), and the present you may be thinking of is שָׂמֵחַ (masculine singular in _kal_).

Comment: Nusach Edot HaMizrach has שַׂמֵּחַ in both places.

Comment: This gets into the question of whose psakim is "nusach sephard" based on?

Comment: Still no answer on the _nusach S'farad_ half of the question. I'll now add a bounty to this.

Comment: @msh210: I don't know where to look, because I don't know who's the arbiter of "Nusach Sephard"

Comment: @Chanoch, there's no arbiter, except to the extent that various rabbis are the arbiters, respectively, of their own _nuschaos_, all of which are collectively known s _nusach S'farad_. That said, anyone (reliable) who asks why the _amida_ has _samach_ while _sheva b'rachos_ has _sameach_ will suffice....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chabad's Siddur Rabbeinu HaZaken has an explanation and comparison [on a footnote in Sheva Berachot](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30450&st=&pgnum=419). The explanation seems to be related to the sephirot of the nikudot, which I know practically nothing about.

Comment: Thanks! 
I actually asked the local Lubavitch _shaliach_ here the _nusach-Haari_ half of my question today, and he said that the _rebbe Rashab_ (5th Lubavitch rebbe, died just after World War One, I think) has a _kuntres_ called _Samach T'samach_ which discusses it. Does anyone know whether that's the "mori chami" quoted in the footnote Chanoch points us to?

Comment: No, "mori vechami" means R' Yosef Yitzchak Schneersohn (6th Lubavitcher Rebbe, father-in-law of the last one). As for Kuntres Samach Tesamach - it discusses the significance of *simchas chassan v'kallah* according to Chassidus, but I'd have to check whether it says anything specifically about the nikkud of these words.

Comment: R' Alex, would checking be possible?

Comment: It's a very long series (hemshech) of maamarim. From a cursory look through it, I didn't see anything on the subject. (And if there was, then the footnote that Chanoch mentioned surely would have brought it up.)

Answer (score 4):

There may be a source for 2 different piel imperatives:

In Mishlei 27:11- חֲכַם בְּנִי וְשַׂמַּח לִבִּי

In Tehilim 86:4 - שַׂמֵּחַ נֶפֶשׁ עַבְדֶּךָ

As far as the double-verb form, the only source I have seen is

Yimiyahu 20:15  - אָרוּר הָאִישׁ אֲשֶׁר בִּשַּׂר אֶת-אָבִי לֵאמֹר יֻלַּד-לְךָ בֵּן זָכָר שַׂמֵּחַ שִׂמְּחָהוּ

But since there seem to be 2 versions, either are fair game.  I'm not sure which of the above versions are more accurate, but we aren't really concerned with mixing two different forms in the same double verb.  More extreme examples of this are "haloch yelech" (Hay-lamed-chaf to yud-lamed-chaf and "asof asifem" (alef-samech-fay to samech-vav-pay).

Comment: Sorry my answer isn't more esoteric.